# how to focus on javascript dynamic windows in webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How can the cursor be focus on a specific input box on page load?

The button is "Add new appointment" the script is:

```
<input type="button" onclick="open_win()" value="add new appointment"/>

 WebElement ek = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='add new appointment']"));
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ek);
```

This opens a pop up window. Now I need to focus on the window.
Ajax is used to retrieve information from this pop up.
I tried every aspect to focus on the new pop up. The input txt fields are hidden, The code that I've tried is:

```
jse.executeScript("window.focus();");

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

driver.switchTo().activeElement().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='barge:bargeId:txtInput']"));

driver.switchTo().alert();
```

I thought to focus on the text field with the following code:

```
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('barge:bargeId:txtInput')[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='barge:bargeId:txtInput']")).sendKeys("suxs");
```

This also haven't worked.
Even `jse.executeScript("document.title")` has not worked.
the code for text field

```
<span id="barge:bargeId:input">
  <input id="barge:bargeId:txtInput" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all inputbox doubleInputbox ui-state-hover" type="text" tabindex="" maxlength="17" accesskey="" name="barge:bargeId:txtInput" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false"/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. to click on the button you can simple do this: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='add new appointment']")).click();`
2. By saying "*This opens a pop up window*" do you mean an actual new window, new tab or dialog like [this](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or like [this](http://www.primefaces.org/prime-ui/dialog.html)?

I think it opens up the `dialog`, and in this case usually it's just another element on the page. And in this case this should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='barge:bargeId:txtInput']")).sendKeys("suxs");
```

**UPDATE:**
Since it's a new window, there ways to switch to the new window [described here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames):

```
driver.switchTo().window("windowName");
```

Also, it would be helpful to check the code of `open_win()` javascript function.

Comment: Alex I can open a new pop up window but the new pop up window Id is not recognizable. I used the WindowHandles but it does not fetch the pop up Window Id.

Comment: @Ram, I've updated the answer. Also post the code for `open_win()` function

Comment: @ Alex, It was a developer's fault they have placed the call function outside the form, so the properties of the form could not render the new page. Thank you so much